# How to keep button element inside parent element with ng-bind-html?

Tags: angularjs

I have code fragment:

```
<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info clearfix">
    <button ng-if="vm.data.LongDescription" ng-click="vm.toggle=!vm.toggle" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right" style="padding: 2px 10px">More...</button>
    {{vm.data.Description}}
</li>
```

where vm.data is the model.

**Question:** Description may contain HTML tags. To render properly I would have to use

```
<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info clearfix" 
ng-bind-html="vm.data.Description">
```

to output description.

If I do that, `button` element inside that `<li>` will be gone, all content of `<li>` will be replaced with description text.

**How can I render HTML description and keep button element?**

Comment: use a `<span>`? or better yet, avoid storing HTML in variables in the first place.

Comment: what span? HTML text is coming from the server, I have no control over it.

Comment: put a `span` in the `li` with the button, and use `ng-bind-html` on it.